# Using Ajax to call the same page makes the body content show twice

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making an Ajax call to the same PHP page from a link on the page. 
For the final code I'll be passing some parameters but for the sake of keeping it simple, I'm not doing that in the code below. Reason I'm using Ajax is to place a "Please Wait" message as it seemed the most effective way to do it (usually you do a call from one page to another, which works perfectly fine).

I do get to see the "Please wait" message accordingly after clicking on the link but it keeps the content of THE `<BODY>` section below the new content being displayed by the Ajax call. So int he example, below, I basically end up with 2 links that say "Click here". How do I make it load just the new content (which in this case is identical)?

This must be simple but I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

**PWAIT.PHP**

```
    <body>
    <?php sleep(3); //To allow for the message to show as I have nothing processing here ?>  
    <a href="#" onclick="loadingAjax('myDiv')">Click here</a>
    <script>
    function loadingAjax(div_id)
    {
     $("#"+div_id).html('<center><img src="http://img/ajax-loader.gif"><b>Please Wait ...
    </b></font></center>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pwait.php",
            success: function(msg){
            $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
        }
    });
}

</script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussions, we've discovered that your code is working exactly as it should. It is doing exactly what you ask it to do.

1. Load the page from the server
2. Click button
3. Loads the same page via AJAX
4. Duplicates the page contents into a div on the page
5. Display duplicate contents

That's what you've asked, that's what you've received.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't `div_id` be the `<div>` where I want the message to be displayed? I'm getting an empty id because it's getting the id of the `<a>` element.

Comment: Yes, of-course. Sorry about that. If this fixes, please accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem, unfortunately. I get a different behavior now where  the "Please wait" message isn't being triggered anymore. I must say that it's quite complex to get such simple functionality in place for a web app for a beginner like me. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: So you click the link and loadingAjax doesn't run? Do you know how to use the Chrome developer tools debugger? You can stop the code execution see and what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I do know how to use developer tools. I'm watching and it runs the ajax call indeed. In fact, I seem to still be facing the same issue. The link still shows twice as before, even with your suggested changes (I had a typo there before).

Comment: I saw your updated answer, thank you, but isn't that the same behavior? 
If I change the url in the ajax call to be the same that I'm in it will create the "Click here"  link twice again. The 404 you see under "Click here" is due to the link not being resolved but if it's a valid page, it will load it underneath the "Click here" link.

Comment: Whoa - I didn't realize you were calling exactly the same URL as the loaded page. Why in the world would you want to do that? Of course it will do as you suggest (load twice), because that is exactly what you've asked it to do.   It is working correctly. It is your expectations that are incorrect.

Comment: You are correct. I did not elaborate the question clearly enough.